How to undo git push origin my_branch --force
I screwed up merge conflicts and pushed changes that are bad. I wanted to "revert" or "get rid of" that commit and go back to the previous commit.
I did this:
git reset --hard <commit_i_want>
git push origin <my_branch> --force

Now, all I have in my branch are the changes from <commit_i_want> only. All other commits before that commit are gone.
In other words, I wanted to remove commit4 only:
commit1 --- commit2 --- commit3 --- commit3 --- commit4 (head)

What I have now is commit3 only, everything else is before that is gone. How can I fix this?

If you set the current state to commit3, that also includes all commits before that. If the changes from previous commit are missing, you accidentally recorded the inverse changes in commit3.

Commits can become invisible, but they remain in your repository for a few days. Search in git reflog show my_branch. In this case, my_branch@{1} would name commit4.

This question is similar to: How can I recover from an erronous git push -f origin master?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
